# Titanium How to Play the Sound from nth second

Tags: android, ios, audio, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have the following code.

```
recording.start();
file = recording.stop();

sound = Titanium.Media.createSound({sound:file});

sound.play();
```

I need to play the recording from duration 15 seconds.

How do i do this?

Comment: Did you try. sound.time = 15.0;

Comment: Yes i tried this it did not work

Comment: I tested it on iPhone and it is working. No sure why not working for you on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [method](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Media.Sound.setTime-method.html) instead of the property?

```
sound.setTime(15);
```